# Hashing a list in a txt file

Tags: python, hash

I just started learning python and trying to put what I learn into practice. Sorry if this is a basic question.

I have a txt file with a list of numbers that I want to hash using python. 
like this:

```
2342342356456
2346573423424
97003093..
```

Searching online, I got as far as

```
import hashlib

with open('myhashlist.txt','wb+') as f:
   b = f.read()
for i in b:
   m = hashlib.md5()
   m.update(bytes(i))
   print(m.hexdigest())
```

I want to save the hashed data back into the file so I replaced 'print' with

```
f.write(m.hexdigest())
```

Doing so just wipes my data in the file. Can someone point me in the right direction? I want to hash a list and then save it to the file.  Also, how can I save it to a new file?  Thank you

Comment: You need to open the file again to write.

Comment: If you open a file in write mode, it truncates the contents.

Comment: "save the hashed data back into the file"... how exactly? Do you want it to overwrite the original data, or perhaps append to the end?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help! I was able to get it to work with komatiraju032's answer.  thank you, komatiraju032!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
import hashlib

with open('data.txt','rb') as fp, open('hash.txt', 'w') as fw:
    [fw.write(hashlib.md5(num).hexdigest() + "\n") for num in fp]
```